# How to do periodic background sync in progressive web apps?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Actually, I want to do background periodic sync in my pwa but,I have searched this at google but don't find the relevant answer that I want!

Comment: The data used by the PWA, or the structure of the PWA? If just the data, you can use setInterval to call your data service as often as you like. e.g. setInterval( () => { this.refreshStaleData(); }, this.refreshHowOften); (This is from an Angular applcation)

Comment: @Mathias I want to register a background periodic sync task that when my app goes closed so my service worker do something in the background after some specific time again and again

Comment: The data used by the PWA, or the structure of the PWA?

Answer (score 7):

Periodic background sync does not currently exist outside of [this proposal document](https://github.com/WICG/BackgroundSync/blob/master/explainer.md#periodic-synchronization-in-design). It's not currently part of any web standard, and no browsers have added support for it inside of their service worker implementation.

While there [is support for background sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) inside of a service worker, it's a one-off, not repeated at a time interval.